# How to Map the column with header csv file data in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am reading the csv files data to using azure data factory dataflow but the csv files does not have any headers so that its loading as below like that data in my source projection column.

[image]

I would like to map some of the column like as below set of position, I need to put decided column name in dataflow source projection column.

> ['_c0', '_c2', '_c8', '_c9', '_c10', '_c11', '_c12', '_c6']

> _c0 -> customerName _c2 -> cusid ..... _c12->depid

I would like to add specfic column name needs to edit or rename dynamically. kindly assist, how do we implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am showing you two ways of renaming the columns.

First is,

[image]

This is my original dataset columns.

Add **Select** transformation to your dataflow,
and you will get option as below.

[image]

Here, add your required names in **Name as** field, as shown above.
You will get result in data preview.

[image]

The other way is using **Derived Column** schema modifier and **Select** transformation.

Add **Derived Column** to dataflow and you will get options as below.
[image]

Here, you can find **Add** option, click on that and add required column name in **Column** field and wanted column from source dataflow in  **Expression** field as shown below.

[image]

After this add **Select** transformation and select the renamed derived columns as below.

[image]

Here is the result.

[image]